# Why was Tuvok's rank different from how he was addressed in the early seasons?

Tags: star-trek

Why was Tuvok wearing lieutenant commander rank, and being referred to as lieutenant then suddenly becoming a lieutenant?  Then later Tuvok is promoted to lieutenant commander and then is referred to as commander at that point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to memory alpha it was just a costume error.

> In "Caretaker" and the first half of season one, Tuvok wore the rank insignia of lieutenant commander, but he was referred to as lieutenant. This costume gaffe was corrected as of "Cathexis".
>
> <sup>[Tuvok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Tuvok), *Memory Alpha*</sup>

From memory the error was never addressed on screen.

Comment: I suppose, in-universe, even Starfleet officers make dumb mistakes. Though to repeatedly address Tuvok by the wrong rank (with no correction from the Vulcan) seems impossible to reconcile. Maybe Q was screwing around?